# How to render an array of components (objects) with specific props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

problem in rendering an array of components. this is my pen [a link](https://codepen.io/babakzy/pen/ZVyvKd). where you can see the result.
there should be 10 cards in result but it does not render them.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state={chng:0}
   }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>Hello from Main!</h1>
    <Card name="sample" />
    <CardsHolder />
   </div>
     )
  }
 }

class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   }
    render() {
    return (<div className="card">{this.props.name}</div>);
     }
   }

 class CardsHolder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }
 render() {
  const cards=[];
  axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/? 
  results=10&inc=name,registered&nat=fr')
 .then(json => json.data.results.map(result => (
  cards.push(<Card key={result.name.first} name={result.name.first} />)
  )))
   console.log(cards)
```

// I think there is correct array of components in Console but it does not render them

```
        return (<ul>{cards}</ul>)
     }
   }

 ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('react-content'))
```

Comment: you shouldn't have api call in render, also the response in async and your code won't work the way you expect it too.

Comment: as @ShubhamKhatri says, you need to change your code a bit like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nsbxre , to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, Notes to takes:

- We do our AJAX requests in `componentDidMount` method so we can fire a render at the very top mount of our component using `setState`
- While doing that thing, Dont store JSX in your component's `state`.

[your code.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YdxZMr)